# How to filter Twit (API) JSON response in node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, twitter

I'm currently writing a small Twitter app using the Twit API. To do what I need to do, I'd like the data to be able to be filtered by user id, and not get all the other garbage JSON spits out. Here's what the response looks like:

```
{ created_at: 'Sat Jun 23 03:45:13 +0000 2018',
  id: 1010368149466697700,
  id_str: '1010368149466697728',
  text:
   'RT @ClassicIsComing: "Let\'s Talk ETC!" Podcast Series by @chris_seberino of @InputOutputHK \nA deep series of powerful intervie
ws with influ…',
  truncated: false,
  entities:
   { hashtags: [],
     symbols: [],
     user_mentions: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     urls: [] },
  source:
   '<a href="https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck" rel="nofollow">TweetDeck</a>',
  in_reply_to_status_id: null,
  in_reply_to_status_id_str: null,
  in_reply_to_user_id: null,
  in_reply_to_user_id_str: null,
  in_reply_to_screen_name: null,
  user:
   { id: 759252279862104000,
     id_str: '759252279862104064',
     name: 'Ethereum Classic',
     screen_name: 'eth_classic',
     location: 'Blockchain',
     description:
      'Latest News and Information from Ethereum Classic (ETC). A crypto-currency with smart contracts which respects immutability a
nd neutrality.',
     url: ,
     entities: { url: [Object], description: [Object] },
     protected: false,
     followers_count: 216255,
     friends_count: 538,
     listed_count: 2147,
```

etc. The code i'm using to get this is:

```
T.get('statuses/home_timeline', {count: 1, exclude_replies: true}, 
function(err, data, response){
    if (err){
        console.log('Uh oh, we got a problem');
    }
    else{
        console.log('We GUUCie bruh');
    }

    var tweets = data;


   /* for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) { 
             console.log(tweets[i]);
         }          */
    console.log(data);


});
```

the last block of code is commented out because I've attempted to define "tweets" as data.id, data.statuses.id, etc, but everything seems to spit out "undefined." I'm a complete noob to javascript and JSON as I'm only currently learning C++ @ school, so any help would be appreciated!

*edit*

I thought I'd add in the error message to show you what happens when I try to treat the data as an object. 
If I try to use JSON.parse(data) as the value for my tweet variable:

```
T.get('statuses/home_timeline', {count: 1, exclude_replies: true}, callBackFunction)

function callBackFunction(err, data, response){
    if (err){
        console.log('Uh oh, we got a problem');
    }
    else{
        console.log('We GUUCie bruh');
    }


    var tweets = JSON.parse(data);



//for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) { 
  //           console.log(tweets[i].id_str);
    //     }          
    console.log(tweets.id_str);

}
```

I get:

```
$ node crypt.js
the bot is starting
We GUUCie bruh
undefined:1
[object Object]
 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

If I try to treat it as an object right away, with:

```
function callBackFunction(err, data, response){
    if (err){
        console.log('Uh oh, we got a problem');
    }
    else{
        console.log('We GUUCie bruh');
    }


    var tweets = data.id_str;



//for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) { 
  //           console.log(tweets[i].id_str);
    //     }          
    console.log(tweets);

}
```

I get:

```
$ node crypt.js
the bot is starting
We GUUCie bruh
undefined
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to transform the response into? What do you count as "garbage"?

Comment: The data you showed isn't an array, it looks like an object. So `tweets[i]` is only going to be defined when `i` is one of the keys like `id_str`. If you just want the user id, use `tweets.user.id`

Comment: @CertainPerformance for instance, I would like to see a response which shows the tweets ids only. I don't care about the tweet text or any other aspect. The "garbage" is just the stuff I don't want, I was just using that term as a linguistic convenience.

Comment: @Mark_M Thanks for the response! Yeah, I get that. Sadly not even that is working. it seems like any time I try to act on the "data" as an object it tells me it's undefined. "data.user.id," "data.id," "data.statuses.id_str" All result in a thrown error of "can't read property X of undefined" where undefined is "data.__"

Comment: Turns out the data was an array. If anyone has this problem in the future, you can iterate through the object with data[i].[datapoint]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

So your line "var tweets = data;" would be "var tweets = JSON.parse(data);"

From there you should be able to interact with the data as if it were an object and grab specifically the id or whatever you're looking for.

I'm also a noob, so I don't have an in depth explanation as to why this works, but it helped fix an issue I had when pulling data from API.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Just tried it, but again it seems to result in this "undefined" error, this time citing "object object":  `$ node crypt.js
the bot is starting
We GUUCie bruh
undefined:1
[object Object]
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
`